# Nil error when trying to call a function in Lua

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

I'm getting a strange error that I can't for the life of me crack.

I'm coding a card game and I have two tables of different lengths. One links entries to functions, and the other holds the played cards. The first table is for attributes that certain cards in the deck have.

```
ATTRIBUTES = {  
        Reset   = RuleBook.Do_Reset,
        Go_Lower= RuleBook.Do_Go_Lower,
        Mirror  = RuleBook.Do_Mirror}
```

The way these functions are called is as follows:

```
ATTRIBUTES[cardPile[#cardPile].Attribute]()
```

I've printed out of contents of both the card object and the ATTRIBUTES table and both are completely in tact. Cards that have an attribute have a table entry under Attribute for a function, and those link up to the Do_... functions. Yet the above line of code doesn't appear to work. If anyone has ideas or suggestions they'd be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't work how? What errors are generated? How do your functions are normally called? Give an example from the `cardPile` table.

Comment: Attempt to call field '?' (a nil value) is the error message I'm recieving. As for how I'm calling my functions; normally as far as I'm aware. This is the only point in the code where functions are called in the manner. One entry from cardPile would be this:
number 1, 
Attribute  function, 
picture 2D.png, 
isSelected = false.
That's what I get from printing out the table

Comment: I tried to [reciprocate](http://codepad.org/gR0yXQTt) your example, and it seems to be working fine. Please provide more code with how you're storing data to `cardPile` table. http://codepad.org/gR0yXQTt

Comment: I store to cardPile in a regular for the loop. http://codepad.org/VdPRkhcx Where cardsToBePlayed is another table that, as you can probably guess, holds card objects that are to be played. The object(s) in this table have a series of validity tests run against then to make sure they are indeed playable.

Comment: In your post you say you have printed the values.  Did you do so immediately before use,  as it could be a scope issue.  Try printing each element in turn directly before calling the statement.

Comment: @user2087398 - give us the whole code please

Comment: Not the *whole* code though. Just something we can run but that showcases the same problem would be best.

Comment: @JaneT Thanks for the reply, yes I printed the tables out immediately before the function call.
- missingno and Egor: Ok. I was thinking it would be best to do that. I think, however, it is probably best to use the whole code as this is a problem that occurs at specific moments during the gameplay. To be more specific, it occurs when either a 2,7,8,10 or Queen card is played. Also, the 'front end' is in Love 2D. I'll have a link ready in a little while. Thanks again for your interest and your replies

Comment: [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/rs1gl8) Here's the code, unfortunately you will need Love 2D to run it, as there is no input recognizing apart from the code looking for mouse releases in certain areas of the GUI (cards, etc). As for the rest of the code, there is at least one other error I'm aware of that I'm in the process of solving (cards being added to the played pile twice) - I'm pretty sure I've got the hang of that one. It's just this one that's killing me. I also tried to get rid of any prints that were made on the fly so the code wont be too confusing.

Comment: Also, there are a lot of comments.

Comment: PLEASE IGNORE THE ABOVE LINK. There's an error which is now fixed in this [link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/qxh2yb) Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua lets you basically use any kind of lua value as a key in a table. The problem with your code above is that your `ATTRIBUTE` table uses strings as the key but `cardPile[#cardPile].Attribute` is a function *NOT* a string.

When you perform the lookup here:

```
ATTRIBUTES[cardPile[#cardPile].Attribute]()
```

You're saying lookup the corresponding value in `ATTRIBUTES` having the key `cardPile[#cardPile].Attribute` which is a function. Your `ATTRIBUTES` table as you have it defined only contain strings as keys -- it has no functions as keys so nil is returned.

Two possible fixes for this:

Assuming `cardPile`'s `Attribute` field already refers to the function you want, you can just call it like this:

```
cardPile[#cardPile].Attribute()
```

The alternative is to change how you setup `card_obj`'s `Attribute` field -- make it refer to a string instead of the the function:

```
function Card.Create(Suit, Number, Name)
  local card_obj = {}
  -- ...
  if( card_obj.number == 1 ) then
    card_obj.Attribute = "Reset"
  elseif( card_obj.number == 6 ) then
    card_obj.Attribute = "Go_Lower"
  -- ... etc.
  else
    card_obj.Attribute = nil;
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much for this answer. I will test it as soon as I can (unfortunately in the mean time a tricky syntax error has popped up that I need to fix). Just to clarify one thing though; when you say "cardPile[#cardPile].Attribute()" I'm assuming you mean this as being in place of the "ATTRIBUTES[cardPile[#cardPile].Attribute]()" line of code?

Comment: yes that is correct. remember you can accept the answer if it solves your question.